# How do I save a reordered list back to the SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, list, linq

Using EF6 and SQL Server.  This question is to ask if I am going in the right direction with my code.

Using a variety of SO posts I was able to define classes that contain lists and incorporate IComparable(Of T).  Although the objects in the lists have properties that can be used for ordering such as dates, I need to maintain a user-defined order that is solely determined by how the user wants the objects arranged.

My first assumption is that I have to maintain a distinct property to maintain the user-defined order.  Is that correct?  This is a very simplified example of what I currently have defined:

```
Class Parent
  :
  Public Property SomeList as List(Of Something)
End Class

Class Something
  Implements IComparable(of Something)
  :
  public property PositionInList as Integer
  Public Function CompareTo(that As Something) As Integer ...
    Return PositionInList.CompareTo(that.PositionInList)
  End Function
End Class
```

And if I write the following:

```
dim aList as New List(Of Something)
aList = Parent.SomeList
aList.Sort()
```

...alist is sorted based on PositionInList as I expected.

If I want to insert a new record into the list, am I responsible for changing the values of PositionInList throughout all the objects in the list? The reason I ask is because the LINQ command of the form `.insert(index,object)` indicates it inserts an element into the List(Of T) at the specified index.  And as I look at the table after the `.insert(index,object)` prior to `SaveChanges()`, the list does have the new object in the correct location, but it didn't set PositionInList to the value of the index specified in `.insert(index,object)`.  Is it supposed to and I haven't coded things correctly?  Also, PositionInList is going to have to ripple the change throughout all the objects - am I responsible for that?

Are there predefined methods I need to learn that would manipulate PositionInList when I insert?

I will also want the user to be able to move items to new positions in the lists.  Are there patterns to do this kind of thing, or once again is that pretty much up to me?

**Added per request in comment below:**

The application is divided into 3 layers: UI, domain, storage.  The storage layer includes a storage service class which has the CRUD methods that interface to the SQL Server.

This is one of the current `Create` methods.  At present it only appends a record at the end of the list.  Per your comment, I will modify it to update PositionInList when the call to `create` requests an insertion somewhere inside the list.  That will require additional parameters not currently coded in the method.

```
Public Overrides Sub ElementCreate(DomainElement As DomainElement)
  Dim aSqlElement As New SqlElement
  aSqlElement.DomainToSqlElement(DomainElement)
  Dim theParent = SqlContext.SqlContents.Include("ContentElements").Where(Function(x) x.ID = aSqlElement.ContentID).SingleOrDefault()
  theParent.ContentElements.Add(aSqlElement)
  SqlContext.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you are responsible for updating that property as the list changes. Can you post the code where you modify the list?

Comment: Thanks for confirming I need to manage the position in list.  I posted just the current  Create method above per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a SortedSet instead so that you don't have to re-sort.

```
Class Parent
:
Public SortedSet<Something> SomeList = new SortedSet<Something>(
  new FuncComparer<Something>( (a, b) => a.PositionInList.CompareTo(b.PositionInList ) ));
End Class
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea when the property you are comparing is mutable.

Comment: he could change the PositionInList property to decimal, then when he wants to add between elements he won't change other object's properties, just make the value it the number in between the two elements he wants to assign against

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Interesting idea to use a decimal, but I get the sense I would eventually have to maintain the PositionInList property, i.e. it doesn't seem like I could keep adjusting the decimal forever, unless I'm missing your point.  However, is it safe to conclude at a minimum your answer implies an agreement with npearson that I have to manipulate PositionInList; there is no 'built-in' method that will do that for me.

Comment: when you save...you would loop through the sorted set and save based on position in the list rather than using the positioninlist variable itself...so when you get back from the database again youd start off with decimals that only have integers in it

Comment: Doh! Of course... and, I actually did that though I was using integers.  Will look into the SortedSet.